# pyspark .collect() function is very slow even for small dataset

Tags: python, optimization, pyspark

Would you guys have any idea why this piece of code takes about 20 minutes to execute, even though I have cached the df?

```
value = df.withColumn("value",1/F.col('col2')).select('value').collect()[0][0]
```

I have few million rows in original dataset but this dataset is already summed-up to one row. Col2 is a summarized value of a another col in original dataset.

I tried to split it in two rows and the problem seems to be this collect function
`value = df.withColumn("value",1/F.col('col2')).select('value')` 50 seconds

`value = value.collect[0][0]`  19 minutes

Comment: What if instead of `.collect()[0][0]` you tried `.head()[0]` ?

Comment: when you just run a `df.cache()` the `df` is marked for caching and it is cached in the next action that is run on the `df`. so, run an action like `.count()` if you're not doing it already.

Comment: @ZygD I think there is the same problem with .head()[0] that it will load everything to the drivers memory.

Comment: it might not be the `collect()`'s fault. you might have terrible joins (sortmerge ones, skewed, etc.) that take a lot of shuffling time. debug your code by looking at the task level DAGs

Comment: There is nothing super terrible. The question is, how I can prevent it running every single step from the past? Maybe I could try to split this notebook in half since caching does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

def collect(self) -> List[Row]:
Returns **all the records** as a list of :class:`Row`.

def take(self, num: int) -> List[Row]:
Returns the first `num` rows as a :class:`list` of :class:`Row`.

def first(self) -> Optional[Row]:
Returns the first row as a :class:`Row`.

Comment: Unfortunately take() and first() are as slow as collect(). This is something to do with memory allocation, since this job trigger 6 spark stages and some of them are heavy. I don't know why that happens since everything has been cached with df = df.cache() command. Sorry, I'm new with pyspark.